# How to make a folder accessible only by a single program?

Tags: bash, password

I want to make a password manager (C is the programming language I'm using) and I decided to make a setup script for it in which you choose where to compile the C code and store the passwords. I decided the simplest way would be to make a directory full of .txt files where the name of the file is the account name, and the text in it is the password. Once you choose the account, the program copies the password to your clipboard. Is there a way to make the folder accessible *only* by using that program (you can't just enter the directory by hand or via another program)?

I'd like to point out that this is just a learning exercise for me. I know it's not optimal.

Comment: You shouldn't store passwords in plain text. Encrypt your file.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new account just for the password manager, set permissions on the directory so only it can access it, and then set the password manager to be owned by said new account with the setuid bit enabled. However, this still isn't nearly as secure as encryption, and note that the root user will be able to bypass this.